# How to update the fk of owner of bidirectional relation in jpa when child is updated

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

## First Definition

Simply, I've 2 entity, first is User and second is Address, every user can have one or more addresses. It means, I want bidirectional OneToMany relation between User and Address.

### Question

I have a user with 3 addresses (User with a list of 3 address) when I update my user and delete some of the addresses (User with list of 2 address) and after that save the user, the fk of addresses is no updated.

> I expect my new user has 2 addresses after the update but the addresses weren't changed.
>
> In Brief: Address table's fk is not updated when I update a list of it from User.

## User Entity (Just address field is written)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLE_NAME)

public class User {

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "User";

//Some Fields Like ID  , name ,...

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Address> addresses;

public List<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}

public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}
}
```

## Address Entity (Just User field is written)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = TABLE_NAME)

public class Address {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "ADDRESS";

//Some Fields Like ID  , name ,...

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonBackReference
private User user;

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

## Service class

```
@Service
public class UserService

@Autowired
UserRepository repository;

public updateUserAddress() {

    //Get User With Id of 1
    User user = repository.findById(1L);

    //Get Addresses
    List<Address> addresses = user.getAddresses();

    //Delete One Address From List
    addresses.remove(0);

    //Set New Address to User Entity
    user.setAddresses(addresses);

    //Save User 
    repository.save(user)

    //It doesn't work (List of Address of user is the same and not changed)

}
```

Btw, I use Spring-data-jpa and Hibernate for DAO layer.

Comment: change the cascadeType of your addresses in Users or delete the address through your addresses list.

Comment: Did you try `orphanRemoval = true`?

Comment: Orphan removal deletes the child, I don't want to delete rows, I want to update the fk of the address table .

Comment: What is your default `FlushModeType` ? Have you tried to `EntityManager.flush()` explicitly?

Comment: I'm using spring data not entity manager!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `removeAddress` method in `User` entity, you can update the fk of the `address` table and also you can keep the row:

```
public void removeAddress(Address address) {
    address.setUser(null); // or the value you want
}
```

The `updateUserAddress` method should be like this:

```
public void updateUserAddress() {

    User user = repository.findById(1L);
    List<Address> addresses = user.getAddresses();

    Address address = addresses.get(0); //the address to be removed
    user.removeAddress(address); 

    user.setAddresses(addresses);

    repository.save(user);

}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    // other fields

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Address> addresses;

    // getters, setters, constructors etc.

    // the remove method
    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
        address.setUser(null);
    }
}
```

Address Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {
    // other fields

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;

    // getters, setters, constructors etc.
}
```